# How to update multiple image in one click button and save it to the database

Tags: angularjs

I have to upload 5 image and save it into the database. But I only have one button. How can I successfully do this please help. I am very new in angular and don't know how to start. When I click the button I get undefined. This is my fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/DharkRoses/hxncw3vm/3/

sample code in my fiddle:

```
angular.module('test', []);

angular.module('test')
.controller('UploadCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {

$scope.thumbnail = {
    dataUrl: 'adsfas'
};
$scope.fileReaderSupported = window.FileReader != null;
$scope.photoChanged = function (files) {
    if (files != null) {
        var file = files[0];
        if ($scope.fileReaderSupported && file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
            $timeout(function () {
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                fileReader.onload = function (e) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope.thumbnail.dataUrl = e.target.result;
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Missed `enctype="multipart/form-data` ?

Comment: If one or more answers are correct you should accept (and upvote if appropriate) one so other users of this site know which one is best and correctly answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that ng-repeat creates a new scope for each item, which is not available outside of the ng-repeat.

The following works because the ng-click is within the ng-repeat.

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4]">
    <td> ID : {{i}}
        <br>Photo:
        <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="file" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required> <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.required">*required</i>
        <img ngf-thumbnail="picFile" class="thumb">
        <button ng-click="picFile = null" ng-show="picFile">Remove</button>
        <br>
        <div style="width:{{picFile.progress}}%" ng-bind="picFile.progress + '%'"></div>
        </span> <span ng-show="picFile.result">Upload Successful</span>
        <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>
        <button ng-click="uploadPic(picFile)">Submit</button> <span class="progress" ng-show="picFile.progress >= 0">
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can solve the problem by creating an scope array in the controller such as:

```
$scope.pics = [
    {picFile: []},
    {picFile: []},
    {picFile: []},
    {picFile: []}
];
```

And the html would use the pics array in the ng-repeat loop.

```
<body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form name="myForm">
        <fieldset>
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="(k, i) in pics">
                    <td> ID : {{k+1}}
                        <br>Photo:
                        <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="i.picFile" name="file" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required> <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.required">*required</i>
                        <img ngf-thumbnail="i.picFile" class="thumb">
                        <button ng-click="i.picFile = null" ng-show="i.picFile">Remove</button>
                        <br>
                        <div style="width:{{i.picFile.progress}}%" ng-bind="i.picFile.progress + '%'"></div>
                        </span> <span ng-show="i.picFile.result">Upload Successful</span>
                        <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button ng-click="uploadPic(pics)">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
        <br>
    </form>
</body>
```